# Read only access on tomcat web application based user roles

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, authorization, tomcat8

Have developed a web application contains 30 jsp pages. Based on user and roles display jsp pages in read only access. How to configure read only access to a tomcat web application. Is there any java design pattern OR tomcat level configuration needs to be done, Please help on this.

Answer (score 1):

Read-only access should be implemented at the application level, not in Tomcat configuration. Forms should be displayed with disabled fields and no buttons to make changes available, or ideally with plain text (not in form fields) as it is easier to read.

It is difficult to say much more because you have not provided any details on what authentication and authorisation system(s) you are using in this application. However, in general terms I can say you will probably want to use `if` statements or polymorphism to implement your solution.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Have read an article modify tomcat catalina.policy to change file permissions.
So same do we apply only read only permissions to war file?

Comment: I am telling you that you have to implement it in JAVA CODE, not with configuration, file permissions or anything like that. Operating system users are not usually the same as web application users so file permissions probably won't work.

Answer (score 1):

A webapp is always read only.

You are mixing two things here. On the one hand in the file system of Tomcat you have files. The permissions of those files relate to what users and services on the operating system can do to those files. The fact that you serve the files on the internet using Tomcat has nothing to do with the permissions on the file system of those files. Apache Tomcat will not grant users on the web the ability to edit the JSP files. The way JSP works is that Tomcat server side will generate HTML from the  JSP and serve that to the user on the client side. So effectively the user through their browser only see HTML CSS and JavaScript that was generated from the JSP. They never see the JSP itself. They cannot change the source of the JSP. if you want to control access to each day is p file separately so that users can only go to web page one or web page 2 you could use access control rules inside your web.xml file for that particular web application. Beyond that you need to look at authorization frameworks such as spring security or implement Java code as already suggested.

With Tomcat you can authenticate your users so that you know you're dealing with Alice or Bob. Through authentication you can assign users roles. With those roles you can define what users can see.